# Alternative to Sandboxie

Tags: windows-7, virtualization

I've been using Sandboxie on 64bit Windows for some time now in order to run multiple instances of one program. The program has been updated and no longer runs in Sandboxie. I am looking for an alternative sandboxing program that is similar to Sandboxie.

It has to have the ability to create multiple independent sandboxes that can be run at the same time (like in the paid version of sandboxie).

I've tried some programs but they all either have only one sandbox or work in a different way. I have tried: BitBox, BufferZone, GesWall, Hopedot VOS, WinJail. The closest match I've found is the Comodo Sandbox but again, it only has one sandbox without the ability to create more.

Are there any other programs that have these features? VM is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying more programs, Avast sandbox is the only acceptable alternative. It does not have multiple sandboxes but it does have an option to run each process independently of other processes in the sandbox and on the system, which can also do.

Out of all the programs that I've tried, Avast is the best alternative to Sandboxie. The sandbox module can be installed separately without any antivirus parts so that's a plus as well.